# How to select DB Expression as value using knex/Bookshelf

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to execute the following query using knex.js and MySql

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    TIME(date_created) AS `timestamp`,
    u.username,
    m.`message`
FROM
    `messages` AS m
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE
    m.game_id IS NULL
AND m.`date_created` > DATE_SUB(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
    INTERVAL 12 HOUR
)
ORDER BY
    m.`date_created` ASC
LIMIT 50
```

For proper handling expressions in where closure such as `DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)` according to documentation there is whereRow() method in knex.
I tried to use select() method as

```
select('messages.id', 'TIME(date_created) AS timestamp', 'users.username', 'messages.message')
```

But knex masks `TIME(date_created)` expression in a way it should to be a column name. Does anybody know a way to use a custom expressions in selects?

Answer (score 2):

I did not found exact answer on my question but I've found a solution which allows me to move forward. I created separate model which uses standard *Bookshelf(knex)* export:

```
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
module.exports.DB = Bookshelf;
```

And created separate method in that model where I could use `DB.knex.raw()` for masking DB expressions in SELECT. So I became able to write the query above in the following way:

```
var DB = require('./../db').DB;
var Messages = DB.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'messages',
        hasTimestamps: false,
        idAttribute: 'id'
    },
    {
        getMessagesHistory: function (gameId) {
            return this.query().select('messages.id', DB.knex.raw('TIME(date_created) AS timestamp'), 'users.username', 'messages.message')
                .innerJoin('users', 'messages.user_id', 'users.id')
                .whereRaw("messages.game_id " + (gameId == 0 ? "IS NULL" : "= " + gameId))
                .andWhereRaw("messages.date_created > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)")
                .orderBy('messages.date_created', 'ASC')
                .limit(50);
        }
    }
);
module.exports = Messages;
```

Comment: Man you made my day, for a continues 3 days I am searching for a solution and never find

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap any argument with `knex.raw()` to tell the framework that it's a raw piece of SQL:

```
select(
  'messages.id', 
  knex.raw('TIME(date_created) AS timestamp'), 
  'users.username', 
  'messages.message',
)
```

See http://knexjs.org/#Raw-Bindings